# Exit from Inno Setup installation from [Code]

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is it possible to exit the installation from a function in the `[Code]` section of an installer created with Inno Setup?

I'm not interested in setting the exit code, what I want to do is perform a custom check for a requirement, and exit the installation if that requirement was not previously installed.

Comment: The question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345920/inno-setup-how-to-abort-terminate-setup-during-install

Answer (score 20):

To prevent the installer from running, when prerequisites test fails, just return `False` from the [`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup). This will exit the installer even before the wizard shows.

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if not PrerequisitesTest then
  begin                     
    SuppressibleMsgBox('Prerequisites test failed', mbError, MB_OK, IDOK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

---

If you need to test prerequisites right before the installation starts only (i.e. the `InitializeSetup` is too early), you can call the [`Abort` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_abort) from the [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    if not PrerequisitesTest then
    begin                     
      SuppressibleMsgBox('Prerequisites test failed', mbError, MB_OK, IDOK);
      Abort;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

---

Though for this scenario, consider using the [`PrepareToInstall` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PrepareToInstall) mechanism, instead of exiting the setup.

```pascal
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
  Result := '';

  if not PrerequisitesTest then
  begin                     
    Result := 'Prerequisites test failed';
  end;
end;
```

[image]

---

If you need to force terminate the installer any other time, use the `ExitProcess` WinAPI call:

```pascal
procedure ExitProcess(uExitCode: Integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpReady then
  begin
    if not PrerequisitesTest then
    begin                     
      SuppressibleMsgBox('Prerequisites test failed', mbError, MB_OK, IDOK);
      ExitProcess(1);
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Though this is rather unsafe exit, so use it only as the last resort approach. If you have any external DLL loaded, you might need to unload it first, to avoid crashes. This also does not cleanup the temporary directory.

[image]

---

Answer (score 15):

You can use **Abort()** if you are in these events:

```
InitializeSetup
InitializeWizard
CurStepChanged(ssInstall)
InitializeUninstall
CurUninstallStepChanged(usAppMutexCheck)
CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall)
```

Answer (score 11):

The way I do it is:

```pascal
procedure ExitProcess(exitCode:integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';
```

And the way of using it is:

```pascal
[Code]
  if .... then begin
     ExitProcess(0);
  end;
```

Comment: While this seems to work from a user perspective it leaves temporary files behind.

Comment: This answer uses Wizard.Close which seems to avoid this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345920/inno-setup-how-to-abort-terminate-setup-during-install

Comment: @JerryDodge You can suppress the prompt. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12849863/382885

Comment: @010110110101 Using `WizardForm.Close` does not work in the silent mode (`/silent`), so the user can easily bypass the check.

Comment: WizardForm.Close also doesn't work on custom pages past ssInstall.

Answer (score 5):

This is a write up of what I fiddled out of my Inno 5.6.1 today and the sources you can find at https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc <sup>[ref1]</sup>

## A possibly useful catch-all solution to "Exit from [Code]"

### TL;DR example:

```
[Code]
var _ImmediateInnoExit_was_invoked_flag: Boolean; // Inno/Pascal Script initializes all Boolean to False.

procedure ImmediateInnoExit();
  var MainFormRef: TForm;
begin
  _ImmediateInnoExit_was_invoked_flag := True;
  try
    MainFormRef := MainForm(); // calls GetMainForm() in Inno pascal code, which will raise an internal exception if the form is not yet initialized.
    Log('INFO: ImmediateInnoExit: Calling MainForm.Close()!');
    Log('NOTE: If the Event Fn CancelButtonClick is not coded to auto-Confirm, this will display the cancel dialog in the GUI case!');
    Log('NOTE: Code will stall inside the Close() function while the Cancel confirmation dialog is displayed.');
    MainFormRef.Close(); // this is only effective if the Wizard is visible, but we cann call it even when running siently (as long as the Wizard is initialized)
    Log('NOTE: MainForm.Close() invoked. (If confirmed, setup will exit.)');
  except
    Log('INFO: ImmediateInnoExit did not resolve MainForm -> assuming we were call in an InitializeSetup() context before the Main form has been created!');
  end;

  Log('INFO: ImmediateInnoExit: Calling Abort() -> EAbort!');
  Log('NOTE: Will exit the current scope.');
  Log('NOTE:   In GUI mode, it will just jump up to the Delphi event loop (and be ignored there). (But the WizardForm.Close() call should lead to exit!)');
  Log('NOTE:   In Silent Mode, it will be caught and exit the setup.');
  Abort(); // Raise EAbort
end;

// This is called when the user clicks the cancel button or the [x] Close button
// the close/cancel can be invoked from code via WizardForm.Close!
procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin

  Log(Format('IN: CancelButtonClick(%d <- Cancel=[%d], Confirm=[%d])', [CurPageID, Cancel, Confirm]));
  Confirm := not _ImmediateInnoExit_was_invoked_flag; // if Confirm==False we don't get the dialog prompt.
  Log(Format('IN: CancelButtonClick(%d -> [%d], [%d])', [CurPageID, Cancel, Confirm]));
end;
```

And now to what the point of the above code is:

## Anatomy of Inno Setup Exit/Cancel and Abort

### `Abort`

The Inno docs for `Abort` state:

> Description: 
>   Escapes from the current execution path without reporting an error.
>
> Abort raises a special "silent exception" which operates like any
>   other exception, but does not display an error message to the end
>   user.
>
> Remarks:
>   Abort **does not** cause Setup or Uninstall to exit **unless** it's **called
>   from** one of these event functions (or another function invoked by
>   them):
>
> `InitializeSetup InitializeWizard CurStepChanged(ssInstall)
>   InitializeUninstall CurUninstallStepChanged(usAppMutexCheck)
>   CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall)`

#### Abort() behaviour explained

The reason the Abort function bevahes in this way is because, internally, Inno raises an `EAbort` exception, and that exception is [treated specially by the Delphi UI loop](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/eabort.html). **Only** in the functions listed, the Inno devs have either added special treatment for `EAbort` (like in the case of `CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`<sup>[ref2]</sup>), --

-- or the function os not called via the UI loop, like in the case of `InitializeSetup`, which is called from the main program in [`Setup.dpr`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Setup.dpr), and any direct `EAbort`is handled there specifically in the `except`block there.

In all other Inno event function (e.g. `NextButtonClick` etc.) the `EAbort`exception will reach the main program/UI loop and be ignored there.

Which leads us nicely to:

#### Abort() behaviour, when running `/SILENT` (or `/VERSILENT`)

When Inno runs silently, it does not display the wizard form UI. The "Wizard" / Inno's progress is then **not** driven by the UI loop, but by `WizardForm.ClickThroughPages`, which is invoked under same toplevel `try/except` block as e.g. `InitializeSetup`. [ref3]

Because of this, if Inno is being called silently, `Abort()` **will exit setup from <strike>every</strike> most `[Code]` functions,** and the list given in the docs for `Abort` becomes moot if setup is being run silently.

### Cancel

To cancel the setup, the user can click the `[Cancel]` button or the `[X]` close button of the Setup Wizard.

In this case, Inno will invoke the callback function [`CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean)`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) (if defined) and terminates setup, possible with an escape hatch dialog:

> Called when the user clicks the Cancel button or clicks the window's
>   Close button. The `Cancel` parameter specifies whether normal cancel
>   processing should occur; it defaults to `True`. The `Confirm` parameter
>   specifies whether an "Exit Setup?" message box should be displayed;

User **`[Code]` can invoke the Cancel Button** mechinism via calling `WizardForm.Close()`, but this only works if Setup is displaying the Wizard Form, and **doesn't work in silent mode**.

#### Cancel Details

`WizardForm.Close`<sup>[ref4]</sup>, or the click on the actual button, will eventually call `TMainForm.FormCloseQuery` (in Main.pas), which will call `CancelButtonClick` callbacks<sup>[ref5]</sup> and dependeing on `Confirm` value, either call `TerminateApp();` directly or first call the helper function `ExitSetupMsgBox()`that will display the message box to the user.

---

---

#### Footnotes:

- [ref1] : For non-delphi folks: If you search over the sources in you text editor, make sure to include at least `.iss .pas` *and* `.dpr`
- [ref2] : ssInstall exception handling is located at [`issrc\Projects\Main.pas`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Main.pas): `TMainForm.Install` via `SetStep(ssInstall, False);` and the `except` block at the end of `TMainForm.Install` where `TerminateApp` is called.
- [ref3] : See `Setup.dpr` calling `MainForm.InitializeWizard` from `Main.pas`which calls `WizardForm.ClickThroughPages` iff `not InstallMode = imNormal`, i.e. in the silent case.
- [ref4] : `WizardForm.Close()` internally calls `MainForm.Close()` (see: `TWizardForm.FormClose`)
- [ref5] : There are actually two kinds of cancel button click callbacks defineable in Inno `[Code]`: The global `CancelButtonClick`procedure, and each Wizard page also has a `OnCancelButtonClick: TWizardPageCancelEvent` that can be set.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at InitializeSetup and Abort in the InnoSetup help.  As Cody said, it is possible.  If you're having problems, post what you've done and the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code section you perform a check. Right?
As result of that check you want to exit the installation.
To perform the exit put the line:

```
PostMessage (WizardForm.Handle, $0010, 0, 0);  { quit setup, $0010=WM_CLOSE }
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: This can be easily by-passed using a silent mode (`/silent`)