# Terminate setup on 32-bit Windows in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using  Inno Setup.

Can someone please tell me how to terminate the setup, if the Windows version is 32-bit?

Or to be more specific, when the setup starts, the code checks if the Windows Version is 32-bit and displays a warning then cancels the setup.

What’s the command to terminate the setup completely?

I'm using the following procedure

```pascal
procedure CheckWindows;
begin
  if not IsWin64 then
  begin
    MsgBox('Error:The Windows version is 32bit',mbError,MB_OK);
    WizardForm.Close;
  end;
end;
```

It does give the warning message but then it allows the user to continue if they want.

How do I completely terminate the installation?

Answer (score 6):

Just return `False` from the [`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup), when you detect a 32-bit system (using the [`IsWin64` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_iswin64)).

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if not IsWin64 then
  begin                     
    SuppressibleMsgBox(
      'Error:The Windows version is 32bit', mbError, MB_OK, IDOK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

See also [Exit from Inno Setup installation from [Code]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438506/850848).

---

Or simply use the [`ArchitecturesAllowed` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesallowed).

See also:

- [Does ArchitecturesAllowed Inno Setup directive concern CPU architecture or operating system architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52187494/850848)
- [Show a custom message for unsupported architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42305206/850848).