# Show a custom message for unsupported architectures

Tags: inno-setup

I use `ArchitecturesAllowed` to only allow installation on 64-bit systems.

When the host architecture is unsupported, the installer shows the following message:

> This program can only be installed on version of Windows designed for the following processor architectures:
>
> x64 *(or x86)*

[image: The architecture unsupported error message]

How can I show a custom message instead of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Handling and customizing errors and messages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65980371/850848).

This particular message is defined by the `OnlyOnTheseArchitectures` message.

You can change it in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection):

```
[Messages]
OnlyOnTheseArchitectures=This program cannot work on your ancient machine. Sorry.
```

[image]

---

Or use your custom implementation for the check, including your own custom message. See [Terminate setup on 32-bit Windows in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24419390/850848).