# Can you force Inno Setup to override or ignore ArchitecturesAllowed with a command line param?

Tags: inno-setup

We are using `ArchitecturesAllowed` and it is working fine at present.

Is it possible to use something like a command line parameter to instruct Inno to "*ignore `ArchitecturesAllowed`, just install it anyway*"?

I don't see anything like this in https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline.  I know its possible to create custom command line params but I don't see how programmatically that would allow for this.

This might be useful for us in some strange corner cases where our installer does not support a particular architecture but we need to work around a customer problem. (Specifically I'm thinking of Windows 11 running in a VM on a Mac, but there could be other cases.)

---

- I know there are approaches like in [Can Inno Setup detect Windows11 on ARM64 hardware which can emulate x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73707415/can-inno-setup-detect-windows11-on-arm64-hardware-which-can-emulate-x64) which allow circumventing `ArchitecturesAllowed` entirely, but that seems like an alternative approach.
- Also I can see that the error message can be customized; but that doesn't change the actual setup behavior: [Show a custom message for unsupported architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305206/show-a-custom-message-for-unsupported-architectures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Using the approach you know ([Can Inno Setup detect Windows11 on ARM64 hardware which can emulate x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73707415/850848)) combined with a custom command line switch is the only way.