# Does ArchitecturesAllowed Inno Setup directive concern CPU architecture or operating system architecture?

Tags: inno-setup

My 64-bit app NEEDS to be installed on a 64-bit Windows Operating System. So I added these two lines in the `[Setup]` section:

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

However, I am confused because the Inno Setup documentation says:

> *ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode*: Specifies the 64-bit **processor**
>   architecture(s)...
>
> *ArchitecturesAllowed*: Specifies which **processor** architecture(s)
>   Setup is allowed to run on

From the documentation it seems these two settings are concerned with the PROCESSOR TYPE. But I have a portable computer with a 64-bit processor but with Windows 10 **32-bit operating system**.

So how can I have a setting in Inno Setup which focuses only on a 64-bit operating system as a prerequisite instead of focusing on the Processor hardware?

Comment: @Martin, I am confused about the answer to that question: Should I follow the presented answer with a script function or should I just use my existing setting like Joshua says?

Comment: OP needs a better answer than the duplicate target.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: It's a worse answer there but a better answer here.

Comment: See also [Terminate setup on 32-bit Windows in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24419390/850848).

Answer (score 0):

Build the installer like that and try it on 32 bit Windows. It will complain about it.

MS started this bad doc trend (that is, using "processor architecture" to mean "OS selected processor architecture" rather than "CPU architecture") and Inno just followed it.

The manual is here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesallowed

> If you install any 32-bit device drivers, you should set this directive to x86

This instruction makes sense only if "Processor Architecture" really means "OS kernel architecture".

Typically, declarative code is better then imperative code.