# Inno Setup Reboot system on fail

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In my Inno Setup project, at some point I run an external command using `exec`, if exitcode return an error, I have to abort installation and exit.

In order to exit installation I tried to use `Abort` and `WizardForm.Close`, in both case, I show a Message through `ShowExceptionMessage`.

The problem is that after I close the messagebox, the system reboot immediatelly without ask me.

There is a way to avoid the system restart or at least show the choice?

I'm using Inno Setup 6.2.0

EDIT:
Below the code:

```pascal
procedure finalizeInstall;
begin
  try
    if not someOperations() then RaiseException('Some operations has failed');
  except
    ShowExceptionMessage;
    WizardForm.Close;
  end;
end;

        
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then finalizeInstall;
end;
```

As described above, in case `someOperations()` fails, after I click OK on `ShowExceptionMessage`, the system restarts immediately.

I tried also to move `WizardForm.Close` to the `CurStepChanged` procedure but the final result is the same.

When I have to abort the installation due to an error, what I would like is to close `WizardForm` *but without the system being restarted automatically*.

The problem is not how Inno Setup determines whether the system should be restarted or not, the problem is to prevent the restart - in case of error - from happening without the user being able to choose whether to do it now or later

Comment: Inno Setup won't reboot without a reason. There something in your specific installer that causes that. We need [mcve].

Comment: The code you have posted will not cause Inno Setup to restart the machine. We need [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved with this: [Exit from Inno Setup installation from [Code]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438506/exit-from-inno-setup-installation-from-code#39788977)
and using the `ExitProcess` WINAPI

Comment: That's not a proper solution. That's a hack.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MartinPrikryl. Do you have please a better suggestion?

Comment: We can give you better suggestions, if you give us [mcve].