# Inno Download Plugin - how detect modal buttons?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin, inno-setup-v6

For our purposes, we decided to use Inno Download Plugin and Inno Setup version 6.2.0

We switched the installer to silent mode to get rid of unnecessary windows and buttons. It turned out somehow like this (I don’t attach idp.iss, it’s unchanged)

```
[code]https://pastebin.com/g7xb6iWj
```

Everything works fine, but there are a couple of but:

**1** There is a Downloading window called by IDP, click on the cross to close the window and in the modal window that appears, confirm with Yes

**Instead of aborting the download, it tries to proceed with the installation and creates shortcuts**

**2** There is a Downloading window called by IDP, turn off wifi, in the modal window that appears where they say "Internet is gone" and ask "Retry or Cancel?" click Cancel

**Instead of aborting the download, it tries to proceed with the installation and creates shortcuts**

I found an explanation here
[Exit from Inno Setup installation from [Code]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438506/exit-from-inno-setup-installation-from-code)

But I can't figure out exactly how to catch buttons in specific modal windows.
And if I'm not mistaken, the second interrupt case is not native and only applies to IDP

**Any ideas to right cancelation of installation of those 2 cases would be great.**

Comment: I guess SO has a rule that pastebin links have to have code added as well. And that would make it a lot easier for people reading your question.  The current ``` formatting of that link just looks broken.

Comment: @StayOnTarget i tried an always error. this tags isnt userfriendly
i am not alone confused with that mysterious code TAGS
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168903/what-does-links-to-jsfiddle-net-must-be-accompanied-by-code-mean

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293510/make-the-must-be-accompanied-by-code-warning-more-direct

Answer (score 0):

My friend did a solution

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.Bevel1.Visible := false;
  WizardForm.MainPanel.Visible := false;
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Top := 50;
  WizardForm.OuterNotebook.height := 400;

  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then begin
    Downloaded := idpFilesDownloaded();
    if not(Downloaded) then begin
      ExitProcess(553);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  if Cancel = True then begin
    ExitProcess(554);
  end;
end;
```